# I'd like to add an edge loop around not connected faces

Tags: edges, loop

So, I'd like to add something like edge loop around these faces to manipulate them (e.g. change size in the middle of each. I'm making a broom, by the way.
).[image]

Comment: use the knife tool with the "cut through" option enabled

Comment: Would like to write an answer, so I can review it review positively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd> to enable, <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut perpendicularly or 45°, <kbd>E</kbd> to keep activated):

[image]